# how to send bitmap from android to php file

Tags: php, android, android-bitmap

I'm developing an mobile android App. And I want to upload images while runtime and save thim to database. I tried alot of methods and I faild!! 
whould you please help me to develop it ? 
my php file is

```
<?php

   require "conn.php";

   $msg ="";
  if (isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
    $target = "uploads/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (url) VALUES ('$name')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$target))
    {
        $msg ="done";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg ="not done";
    }
  }

?>
```

I know how to save from php to database and aslo retrieve 
my problem is how to send from android to PHP ?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried on the Android side?

Answer (score -1):

first convert your bitmap into base64 and then send it to your server

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
String base64OfBitmap = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: base64 makes files 33% larger.  Why would you do this when you could just upload a file correctly over HTTP?

Comment: Yep, I read the question and understand the problem at hand.  Your solution just addresses the problem in a very inefficient way.  I'm curious what benefit comes from doing it through base64 versus binary?

Comment: i m just 19 and by looking at your dp u seems to be an uncle for me. i cant argue with you. i m sry. i lost. i have a huge respect for your words. good time ahead

Comment: I apologise, I didn't mean to make you feel lost.  Your suggested solution would definitely work, I just wanted to draw your attention to the issue!

Comment: thats your greatness that you apologise whitout any mistake :) have good time and thanks for correcting me. i ll improve myself